# Spring Security: global method security not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have configured Keycloack and my auth server is working fine but since Spring deprecated previous OAuth2 support I am not sure my configuration is acurate. Its a simple learning application and I am trying to add Pre-authorization on method level so that the current authenticated user can add their workout data and view them for themselves. It also restricts delete endpoints only to admin user (fitnessadmin)  But I am confused on configuration.

MY Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workout")
public class WorkoutController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkoutService workoutService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void add(@RequestBody Workout workout) {
        workoutService.saveWorkout(workout);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Workout> findAll() {
        return workoutService.findWorkouts();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        workoutService.deleteWorkout(id);
    }
}
```

the repository class

```
public interface WorkoutRepository extends JpaRepository<Workout, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT w FROM Workout w WHERE w.user = ?#{authentication.name}")
    List<Workout> findAllByUser();
}
```

service class

```
@Service
public class WorkoutService {
    
    @Autowired
    private WorkoutRepository repository;
    
    @PreAuthorize("#workout.user == authentication.name")
    public void saveWorkout(Workout workout) {
        repository.save(workout);
    }
    
    public List<Workout> findWorkouts() {
        return repository.findAllByUser();
    }
    
    public void deleteWorkout(Integer id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").hasAuthority("fitnessadmin")
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
          .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt());
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension 
                       securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
       return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
server: 
  port: 8086

spring:
  datasource:  
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?useSSL=false 
    username: username  
    password: password
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master
          
claim:
  aud: fitnessapp
```

I have 3 users as mary, bill, rachel and only mary is "fitnessadmin" and would be able to delete.Rest of the users are "fitnessuser"

Here is the decoded token:

```
{
  "exp" : 1635741988,
  "nbf" : null,
  "iat" : 1635734788,
  "auth_time" : null,
  "jti" : "9b319b1b-7687-4842-b211-02e3d1aaec3c",
  "iss" : "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master",
  "aud" : "fitnessapp",
  "sub" : "8fe23dba-d692-4933-9bca-c5f69ff3d408",
  "typ" : "Bearer",
  "azp" : "fitnessapp",
  "nonce" : null,
  "session_state" : "c471f77f-8efa-449b-982d-90ea942f329e",
  "at_hash" : null,
  "c_hash" : null,
  "name" : null,
  "given_name" : null,
  "family_name" : null,
  "middle_name" : null,
  "nickname" : null,
  "preferred_username" : null,
  "profile" : null,
  "picture" : null,
  "website" : null,
  "email" : null,
  "email_verified" : null,
  "gender" : null,
  "birthdate" : null,
  "zoneinfo" : null,
  "locale" : null,
  "phone_number" : null,
  "phone_number_verified" : null,
  "address" : null,
  "updated_at" : null,
  "claims_locales" : null,
  "acr" : "1",
  "s_hash" : null,
  "trusted-certs" : null,
  "allowed-origins" : null,
  "realm_access" : null,
  "resource_access" : null,
  "authorization" : null,
  "cnf" : null,
  "scope" : "fitnessapp",
  "sid" : "c471f77f-8efa-449b-982d-90ea942f329e",
  "user_name" : "bill",
  "authorities" : [ "fitnessuser" ]
}
```

As I mentioned my confusion is with configuration class. This implementation gives below errors on different endpoints:

findAll():

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'authentication' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

add():

```
403 Forbidden
```

A help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
I think I was missing SecurityEvaluationContextExtension as suggested in the comment and I have updated the code, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you registered `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` as a bean to using Spring Data + Spring Security?

Comment: That was very important and I missed it but I still get unauthorized error

Comment: So weird! So one thing I want you to confirm here is, trying call `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = authentication.getName();` before you call `repository.findAllByUser()` to see that whether the `name` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error you need to fix is authentication object in query.

```
public interface WorkoutRepository extends JpaRepository<Workout, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT w FROM Workout w WHERE w.user = ?#{authentication.name}")
    List<Workout> findAllByUser();
}
```

Authentication is not an object you can access with this way but if you want to access spring bean you can create Authentication.java and create name field in that class.

Best way will be

```
public interface WorkoutRepository extends JpaRepository<Workout, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT w FROM Workout w WHERE w.user =:name")
    List<Workout> findAllByUser(@Param("name") String name);
}
```